# How memory is managed for C# objects when C++ code uses as C# class?

Tags: c#, c++, memory, memory-management, managed-c++

How memory is managed for C# objects when C++ code uses as C# class?

NOTE: I am not specific in this question but just wondering how it is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works exactly the same... objects that are not reachable by managed code are eligible for garbage collection so if your unmanaged code is relying on managed resources to continue existing you must hold a reference to it somewhere in the c# side of the app.

edit: this applies to unmanaged c++

Comment: Suppose I have a scenario in which my managed c++ code is calling C# class server which returns an array or anobject (i.e. I am assuming object memory will be allocated on managed heap). Now my doubt is how this C# object memroy is used by c++ code

Comment: As yaur said, the same way like from a C# class. The C++ code h is going to wrap them in a managed pointer that it informs the GC about. These pointers, as long as tehy exist, count as reference and stop garbage collection. THere was once a GcRoot template for that. These days it is more transparent, but the approach is the same.

Comment: I don't think I have ever run into a case where I had to return an array from c# to c++.  You would have to either marshal it out to unmanaged memory or pin the array, either of which means that you are going to have to do some work to avoid memory leaks.  c++/cli (what you are calling managed-c++) is a little more straight forward because it handles a lot of that marshaling behind the scenes IIRC from the managed bit of your c++/cli assembly is exactly the same as if it were c# and the complex part is between the manged and unmanaged parts of that assembly.

Comment: Note that it is not sufficient to merely "hold a reference". **The reference must be guaranteed to stay alive even if the jitter is optimizing it away.**  Use the **KeepAlive** method to ensure that an object being used in unmanaged code stays alive.

Answer (score 0):

Managed C++ uses the ordinary garbage collector.